# What does template<class = enable_if_t<...>> do?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, variadic-templates, sfinae

I have been reading STL files to learn better ways to format my code, and to learn tricks to be more efficient. I have been reading the thread files and I can't figure out what some of the code does.

```
template<class _Fn,
    class... _Args,
    class = enable_if_t<!is_same<decay_t<_Fn>, thread>::value>>
    explicit thread(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
    {   // construct with _Fx(_Ax...)
    ...
    }
```

`std::enable_if_t` is

```
template<bool _Test,
    class _Ty = void>
    using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Test, _Ty>::type;

template<class _Ty>
    struct enable_if<true, _Ty>
    {   // type is _Ty for _Test
    using type = _Ty;
    };
```

that code is all copyrighted in the thread and str1common STLs.

my only question is what does the `class = enable_if_t<...>` do?

Comment: That's an unnamed template parameter with a default argument. It's just there to make sure the [`enable_if_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) resolves to a type.

Comment: A good read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: I would certainly not recommend you read STL files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look for S.F.I.N.A.E.: "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error".

See a possible implementation of `std::enable_if` (`std::enable_if_t` is only a helper `using`, C++14 introduced, to access the `type` in a simpler way)

```
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Is made so *iff* (if and only if) the template boolean value (the first template parameter) is `true`, `std::enable_if<...>::type` is defined (with the type in the second template parameter; `void` if unexpressed).

To make it simple, you have that, in your example

```
template<class _Fn,
    class... _Args,
    class = enable_if_t<!is_same<decay_t<_Fn>, thread>::value>>
    explicit thread(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
    {   // construct with _Fx(_Ax...)
    ...
    }
```

`enable_if_t` (that is `typename std::enable_if<...>::type)` is available iff the first value (`!std::is_same<typename std::decay<_Fn>::type, thread>::value`) is `true`.

That is:

- if `!std::is_same<typename std::decay<_Fn>::type, thread>::value` is `true`, the substitution `class = enable_if_t<!is_same<decay_t<_Fn>, thread>::value>>` is performed and the function is implemented
- if `!std::is_same<typename std::decay<_Fn>::type, thread>::value` is `false`, the substitution `class = enable_if_t<!is_same<decay_t<_Fn>, thread>::value>>` fail, the function isn't implemented *but* this ins't an error (SFINAE).

Why the language permit this?

Because, by example, you can implement two version of the function

```
template<class _Fn,
    class... _Args, //  vvvv true case
    class = enable_if_t<true == is_same<decay_t<_Fn>, thread>::value>>
    explicit thread(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
    { /* do something */ }

template<class _Fn,
    class... _Args, //  vvvvv false case
    class = enable_if_t<false == is_same<decay_t<_Fn>, thread>::value>>
    explicit thread(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
    { /* do something else */ }
```

Suggestion: search for SFINAE and study it because is an important part of modern C++.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is what I thought it was doing but I couldn't really find anything to support that idea. The SFINAE is exactly the kind of thing I am looking to learn more about.